# Close activity without showing it

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle

I have two activities in my code, let A&B. From A, I use an intent to start B and when B starts, I start a notification.

Now the problem is, when I close the notification, if B is visible to the user, it should go back to A, else when a user opens the app from a recent task A should show up.

My idea:
I thought of declaring an integer(*visible*) as 1 in *onResume* and 0 in *onPause* . So I can check it using if in *onCreate*. But with *onCreate*, *onResume* will be called.**How to overcome this?**

**Edit:**
I am trying to develop a music player. A is the file selector activity and B is the player activity. I need to do notification in B itself because it is a foreground notification using a service(I need the player to run in the background). So if I close the notification while the app is open, the player also must close, else next time I open the app, again file selector must show.

Comment: please don't use the android studio tag, unless it's specifically regarding a feature of the IDE

Answer (score 1):

Here what you wanna do.
Class a :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,b.class);
startActivity(intent);

protected void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   showNotification();
}
public void showNotification()
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"channelID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Description")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int notificationId = 1;
    createChannel(notificationManager);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
}

public void createChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
        return;
    }
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channelID","title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

So, you wanna do that if notification close/remove from notification-bar than it will back you to class A

Then, check that notification remove or not in class B.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question(probably because I asked the question in a weird way) . I am trying to develop a music player. A is the file selector activity and B is the playeractivity. I need to do notifiction in B itself because it is a foreground notification using a service(I need player to run in background).So if I close the notification while the app is open,the player also must close, else next time I open the app,again file selector must show.

Comment: So, check service is running or stopped in class `B`. If stopped than `finish()` `bActivity`

Comment: But ,there is a problem.If I open another app in foreground and close the notification,my app opens to show the file selector.I don't want that because it interrupts user experience

Comment: @ADP So, you have to check twice things. User is running your application in background or not. If not than you can do it easily. Run code `onDestroy` if service is turned off than don't do anything. If user is running your application(music player) in background than you have add a value `onPause` then if user stop the service than check the value. Then, do things depending on that `value`. You can add value in `onDestroy` also. I hope it might help you.